# Missing class com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.ForcedSender

Tags: android, crashlytics

After updating Crashlytics from 18.2.13 to 18.3.0 release build showed the following R8 warning:

> Missing class com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.ForcedSender (referenced from: void com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.send.ReportQueue.lambda$flushScheduledReportsIfAble$0(java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch))

Comment: Now fixed in 18.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Crashlytics 18.3.1 (and BOM 31.0.1) fixes this issue. For more information see the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4223) here.

Add the following to your gradle dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime:3.1.8"
```

Crashlytics 18.3.0 adds dependency for Transport Runtime 3.1.7 which is missing the `ForcedSender` class.

Comment: Although this may solve the crash, this seems like a workaround to an issue that the Firebase team may have introduced. I would consider filing an issue against Firebase for this if one does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (for me) is simply to upgrade to BOM 31.0.1! Make sure you trigger the gradle sync again to see the effect.